# How can I find minimum of the expression $y - 5 x$ knowing that $y \log _{3}(3 x+y+9)=\left(x^{2}+3 x+y\right) \log _{3}(x+3)$?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, output-formatting

I am trying to find minimum of `y - 5 x` knowing that `y  Log[3, 3 x + y + 9] == (x^2 + 3 x + y) Log[3, x + 3], x >= 0, y >= 0`. I tried

```
Minimize[{y - 5 x, 
   y  Log[3, 3 x + y + 9] == (x^2 + 3 x + y) Log[3, x + 3], x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}] // Simplify
```

I got

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
sol = NMinimize[{y - 5  x, 
   y   Log[3, 3  x + y + 9] == (x^2 + 3  x + y)  Log[3, x + 3], 
   x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}]

(* {-1., {x -> 1., y -> 4.}} *)

Show[
 ContourPlot[y - 5 x, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
  Contours -> Range[-21, 4, 5]],
 ContourPlot[
  y   Log[3, 3  x + y + 9] == (x^2 + 3  x + y)  Log[3, x + 3],
  {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}],
 Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{x, y} /. sol[[2]]]}]]
```

[image]